# Multi-part geometries do not themselves provide the array interface

Tags: qgis, python, clip, ogr, shapely

## So initially I had multiple perpendicular lines along a coastline.

[image]

## Next I clipped these lines based on polygons along the coastline,such as the follwing.

[image]

I am trying to use this resulting shapefile to get the pixel values from a raster based on these clipped lines. The problem is that I am not being able to iterate over these as I would before I clipped them.

## This is the script I'm trying to use

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString, LineString, Point
from shapely import wkt

raster = rasterio.open(r'C:\Users\Cassiano\DATA_ANALYSIS\MAPBIOMAS\1985\mapbiomas-riograndedosul-1985.tif')
band = raster.read(1)
ds = ogr.Open(r'C:\Users\Cassiano\DATA_ANALYSIS\MAPBIOMAS\LINHAS\RS.shp')
layer = ds.GetLayer(0)

#Setting lists to store data
x = []
y = []
z = []
line_id = []
# distance of the topographic profile
distance = []
dist = 0.03 / 111.139
```

## This is the snippet that really matters

```
for line in layer:
        line_points = []
        cur_dist = dist
        line_geom = line.geometry().ExportToWkt()
        shapely_line = LineString(wkt.loads(line_geom))
        line_len = shapely_line.length
        while cur_dist < line_len:
            point = shapely_line.interpolate(cur_dist)
            xp, yp = point.x, point.y
            line_id.append(line.GetFID())
            x.append(xp)
            y.append(yp)
            #get pixel value
            row, col = raster.index(xp, yp)
            z.append(band[row, col])
            distance.append(cur_dist)
            cur_dist += dist
profile = zip(line_id, x, y, z, distance)
```

## This is the error message

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-2f8fa74d07bc> in <module>()
      3         cur_dist = dist
      4         line_geom = line.geometry().ExportToWkt()
----> 5         shapely_line = LineString(wkt.loads(line_geom))
      6         line_len = shapely_line.length
      7         while cur_dist < line_len:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in __init__(self, coordinates)
     46         BaseGeometry.__init__(self)
     47         if coordinates is not None:
---> 48             self._set_coords(coordinates)
     49 
     50     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py in _set_coords(self, coordinates)
     95     def _set_coords(self, coordinates):
     96         self.empty()
---> 97         ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
     98         if ret is not None:
     99             self._geom, self._ndim = ret

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py in __array_interface__(self)
    792     def __array_interface__(self):
    793         """Provide the Numpy array protocol."""
--> 794         raise NotImplementedError("Multi-part geometries do not themselves "
    795                                   "provide the array interface")
    796 

NotImplementedError: Multi-part geometries do not themselves provide the array interface
```

In order to get the lines clipped I used the clip method from QGIS with the lines and the polygons. 
This script has worked for other shapefiles, I started getting this error message only after clipping with QGIS.

I decided to use QGIS because I was having some trouble clipping the lines by writing my own code, though I don't understand what could've compromised the geometries since whenever I try the argument

```
line.geometry().GetGeometryName()
```

The result is always a 'LineString' or a 'MultiLineString', therefore iterating through these features shouldn't be a problem... I guess.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. Solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/73354885/4288232 This might be caused by incompatibility of shapely 1.7 and numpy 1.23. Either update shapely to 1.8 or downgrade numpy, otherwise it might not work.